# How to retrieve the value of an auto generated key object inside another object in Firebase IOS?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database

So this is my database structure which has "plastic" as a main object and when user input something new into the database it will generated a new item separately and sequentially with unique key as shown in the image. My problem is I want to retrieve all the value inside those child object individually such as name and price. However, what I can do now is to retrieve everything inside "plastic" object and the result is all they key with key value pair inside which is something I don't expect to get.

[Here is my database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQkVr.png)

What I want to get is all those name and price which is located inside the autogenerated key. I have tried printing the "plastic" object and the result is just not what I expected to get by showing all the key and the value both at the same time.

[Here is the result I get in Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lASSK.png)

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you've already tried. Without that, it is unlikely that we'll do a better job helping you than the Firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#listen_for_child_events), or [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-ios-swift/) already do.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Hi, I have just edited my question. May you please look at it? Its all about retrieving data from an auto generated key inside an object.

Comment: Please: 1) don't share screenshots of textual content. Instead share the text itself, so we can copy/paste it, search it, etc. For the JSON, you can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data). 2) share the actual that you run to get the problem. Also see: [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)